# Invoke Chrome MSI via powershell

Tags: google-chrome, powershell, windows-installer

I'm trying to build a script that will download chrome msi file then check if I have this version stored locally if not keep it otherwise delete it. My goal is to keep a local version of each Chrome release so I can test my apps aganist if I ever run to an issue with a coustomer. 
I build different scripts to do each piece yet the issue now is, when I download the msi file and I look into its info via right-click -> properties -> details it says the version is 58.But when I use the powershell to get the info of the msi it says the version is 66. Is there away that I can invoke the description section then the comment section to get the true version. I'm using this url to get the latest msi

```
 https://dl.google.com/dl/chrome/install/googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi
```

and I'm using this script to get the info of the msi file

```
param(
[parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
[ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
[IO.FileInfo]$Path
)
$WindowsInstaller = New-Object -com WindowsInstaller.Installer
$MSIDatabase = $WindowsInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember("OpenDatabase","InvokeMethod",$Null,$WindowsInstaller,@($Path.FullName,0))
$View = $MSIDatabase.GetType().InvokeMember("OpenView","InvokeMethod",$null,$MSIDatabase,"SELECT * FROM Property")
$View.GetType().InvokeMember("Execute", "InvokeMethod", $null, $View, $null) | out-null
while($Record = 
$View.GetType().InvokeMember("Fetch","InvokeMethod",$null,$View,$null)) 
{
@{ $Record.GetType().InvokeMember("StringData","GetProperty",$null,$Record,1) = 
   $Record.GetType().InvokeMember("StringData","GetProperty",$null,$Record,2)}
}
$View.GetType().InvokeMember("Close","InvokeMethod",$null,$View,$null) | out-null
```

I use -Path parameter to give it the file path.

and that's what I get and as you can see it says the version is 66

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
UpgradeCode                    {C1DFDF69-5945-32F2-A35E-EE94
AllowDowngradeSubstitution     false
ALLUSERS                       1
ARPNOMODIFY                    1
Manufacturer                   Google, Inc.
ProductCode                    {A4690197-328E-3732-A460-124D
ProductLanguage                1033
ProductName                    Google Chrome
ProductVersion                 66.245.16480
SecureCustomProperties         NEWPRODUCTFOUND;UPGRADEFOUND
```

Comment: You may want to check the [Summary Information Stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372045) to see if the 58 shows up there. I believe Explorer shows SIS data rather than Property table data. But, uh, do you have a question?

Comment: My main question is how to get the true version of that Chrome MSI file, does not matter if it's with PS or CMD, or VB. Thanks.